# adobe animate virtual camera can't pin camera

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe

I'm trying to utilize the pinCameraToObject in virtual camera in adobe animate cc 2019.
Documentation: https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/working-with-camera-in-animate.html#Lockingalayerwithcamera

the problem is it doesn't do as it says it should, it doesn't pin, infact it does nothing. Other features such as setPosition work, but not pin. I have a movieclip mc on the stage that I want to pin to. I've checked and made sure movieclip is loaded on stage and all childrens to be declared on run has been enabled. When I move the mc movieclip the virtual camera does not follow.

My code:

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import fl.VirtualCamera;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Cam extends MovieClip {

        public var cameraObj = fl.VirtualCamera.getCameraAsMovieClip(root);
        public function Cam() {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, reportKeyDown);
            cameraObj.pinCameraToObject(getChildByName("mc"), 200,50);
        }
        public function reportKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W) {
                mc.x = mc.x + 25;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question but I noticed the VirtualCamera does not affect MovieClip objects instantiated programmatically. In other words, it only works with Symbols that were manually placed on the canvas. Could that be the reason for pinning not working in your case?